# InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls when using onclick AuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, invalidoperationexception

I am doing a semester project with my group (https://github.com/Tymon2115/ABDOT), and right now I am trying to create login functionality in blazor.

The problem I have is that when I log in i get correctly authorized, but I would like to get the returned User ID so I can load user's profile page and so on, but I get that exception.

**Code**:

```
<NotAuthorized>
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>@confirmationMessage</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="e-mail" @bind-value="email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" @bind-value="password"/>
        </div>
        <div style="color:red">@errorMessage</div>
        <p class="actions">
            <button class="btn-outline-dark" @onclick="PerformLogin">Login</button>
            <button class="btn-outline-dark" @onclick="Cancel">Cancel</button>
        </p>
    </NotAuthorized>
```

```
@code{
public async Task PerformLogin()
    {
        errorMessage = " ";
        Console.WriteLine("logging in");

        try {
            User returnedUser = await ((CustomAuthenticationStateProvider) AuthenticationStateProvider).ValidateLogin(email, password);
            email = "";
            password = "";
            Id = returnedUser.Id;

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            errorMessage = e.Message;
            throw;
        }
            
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        
        
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider {
        private readonly IJSRuntime jsRuntime;
        private readonly IUserService userService;
        private User cachedUser;

        public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IJSRuntime jsRuntime, IUserService userService)
        {
            this.jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
            this.userService = userService;
        }
        

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            if (cachedUser == null)
            {
                string userAsJson = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", "currentUser");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAsJson))
                {
                    cachedUser = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(userAsJson);
                    identity = SetupClaimsForUser(cachedUser);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                identity = SetupClaimsForUser(cachedUser);
            }

            ClaimsPrincipal cachedClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(cachedClaimsPrincipal));
        }

        public async Task<User> ValidateLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Validating log in");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) throw new Exception("Enter username");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new Exception("Enter password");
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            try
            {
                User user = await userService.ValidateUser(username, password);
                identity = SetupClaimsForUser(user);
                string serialisedData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
                await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "currentUser", serialisedData);
                cachedUser = user;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity))));
            return cachedUser;
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            cachedUser = null;
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "currentUser", "");
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
        }
        
        private ClaimsIdentity SetupClaimsForUser(User user)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
            ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "apiauth_type");
            return identity;
        }
}
```

**Exception:**
(line 58 refers to Id = returnedUser.Id;)

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at LoginComponent.Login.PerformLogin() in C:\Users\arasi\RiderProjects\SEP3\ABDOT\ABDOTClient\Pages\Login.razor:line 58
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at LoginComponent.Login.PerformLogin() in C:\Users\arasi\RiderProjects\SEP3\ABDOT\ABDOTClient\Pages\Login.razor:line 58
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.CircuitHost[111]
      Unhandled exception in circuit 'VJ0s6w5s4S8AbQPvcPggB1YWq20QhnTjnS1IiTU7A8I'.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at LoginComponent.Login.PerformLogin() in C:\Users\arasi\RiderProjects\SEP3\ABDOT\ABDOTClient\Pages\Login.razor:line 58
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
getting client
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be perfor
med during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime.BeginInvokeJS(Int64 asyncHandle, String identifier, String argsJson, JSCallResultType resultType, Int64 targetInstanceId)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] args)
         at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
         at ABDOTClient.Authentication.CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync() in C:\Users\arasi\RiderProjects\SEP3\ABDOT\ABDOTClient\Authentication\CustomAuthenticationStateProvider.cs:line 32
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(Int32 componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.CreateInitialRenderAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c__11`1.<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedServerComponentAsync(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, Object parameters)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
         at ABDOTClient.Pages.Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__14_1() in C:\Users\arasi\RiderProjects\SEP3\ABDOT\ABDOTClient\Pages\_Host.cshtml:line 21
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
         at ABDOTClient.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Users\arasi\RiderProjects\SEP3\ABDOT\ABDOTClient\Pages\_Host.cshtml:line 5
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompl
eted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: What's the exception that you actually get? Also, when rethrowing, use `throw;` instead of `throw e;` in order to get a proper stack trace

Comment: I edited the post and put the exception that I get @AluanHaddad

Comment: Can you clarify what the object/class `User` is here: `User user = await userService.ValidateUser(username, password);` ?